# Right Click and save link to open in new tab

Tags: javascript, jquery

I added a custom right click menu in my project using jquery and now what I am trying to achieve is:

-> If anyone right click on a link then an option will show "Open link in new tab" and after selecting the option it will open in new tab with that link.

-> Else It disable "open link in new tab" option and works as default.

I used Jquery in project. So, any solution weather jquery or pure js will be appriciated. :D

Comment: You need to post the code you have, showing us what you tried and where you got stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you need a link with a "target" attribute.
Assuming you already have links `<a>` in your menu, just add

```
target="_blank"
```

in it for it's open in a new tab.
You can add this attribute dynamically, via jQuery, when needed.

```
$("#mylink").attr("target","_blank")
```

Answer (score 1):

@technico 's answer, or if you want to do it programmatically, use `window.open("yourlink.here")` as you seems to copy the link.

`window.location.href = "yourlink.here"` for the same window.